# Matplotlib secondary log x-axis with descending values, primary x-axis linearly increasing

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been trying to wrangle matplotlib's secondary x-axis function to generate a plot and have been having a difficult time. I'm looking at the evolution of a parameter with respect to altitude (linear scaling) as well as column density (logarithmic scaling). The column density axis is coming out backwards from what I was expecting.

Plotting versus altitude is no problem, but the issue comes in when I try to add a secondary x-axis to represent column density. The function to go from altitude (`a`) to column density (`n`) is as follows:

```
n = integral(n_0 exp(-m*a) da)
```

where `n_0` & `m` are positive numbers. So, increasing altitude means decreasing column density. I think this is what is throwing matplotlib for a loop. My code right now is below:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))  
plt.rcParams['font.size']=14  
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)  
alts = column_density_to_altitude(cds)  

ax1.plot(alts, f0_hplus_cd[0,:], c='navy', label='F$^0$(E=1 keV)')  
ax1.plot(alts, f0_hplus_cd[1,:], c='blue', label='F$^0$(E=2 keV)')  
ax1.plot(alts, f0_hplus_cd[2,:], c='skyblue', label='F$^0$(E=3 keV)')  
ax1.legend()
ax1.set_title('Evolution of ENA Fraction vs. Altitude')  
ax1.set_ylabel('Neutral Percentange [%]')  
ax1.set_xlabel('Altitude [km]')  

ax2 = ax1.secondary_xaxis(-0.2, functions=(calculate_column_density, column_density_to_altitude))  
ax2.set_xscale('log')  
ax2.set_xlabel('Column Density [cm$^{-2}$]')  
plt.tight_layout()  
plt.show() `
```

StackExchange won't let me include an image because I'm new here.

The functions to-and-from column density are working properly, but the column density axis is backwards (i.e., the column density is *increasing* with increasing altitude, when it should be *decreasing*). Any ideas? I tried reversing the primary axis, reversing the secondary axis, and adjusting the axis tick labels, but none of those worked.

Comment: This would be easier to help with a self-contained example, instead of code fragments.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: That said, you, in general, cannot have the secondary axis have a different transform (log in your case) than the main axis.  You will get weird behaviour.

Comment: If the ticks on the secondary axis are logarithmic, then you can still use a logarithmic locator and formatter without changing the scale.

Comment: Hard to say without a reproducible example, but sicne you say your functions are producing the correct results and this is just a plotting issue, a _super_ clunky workaround could be to use `twiny()` instead of a secondary X axis, and make sure the `xlim` is set precisely

Comment: @astroChance, I ended up doing just that.  It's super duper clunky, but I managed to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you tried reversing the primary/secondary axes, does that mean you tried inverting the column density axis with the invert function?

```
ax2.invert()
```

After inverting, the secondary axis should display column density decreasing as altitude increases.

Comment: Yes, I tried ax2.invert_xaxis(),and it didn't change anything.  The column density axis was still displayed incorrectly.